# It is possible to access android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE with show request permission dialog to user?

Tags: android, android-permissions

[image]

**Tried like this but always permission is denied and can't able to modify system permission.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packagename"
    coreApp="true"
    android:sharedUserId="packagename"
    android:sharedUserLabel="@string/app_name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

In screenshot some applications are in list of modify system permission so,Which permissions are valid for request to user. Is this possible to use android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE by valid way ????

Comment: Modify_phone_state is reserved for system apps only.

Comment: can we use it any way @SadiqMdAsif ??

Comment: Nope. You just can't get it. but can you please mention what are you actually trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Yeh It is possible. After Android 6 , chooses runtime permission and we can give permission using custom or system dialog

[Check this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: It is possible to access android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE ??

Comment: You can not grant system permission in that way. Please read carefully!